# my validation code on form isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I created a form that posts data to an API url and I want these fields to be validated (e.g. when empty, show an error message).

I tried to validate through if statements inside my `postData` method but it always returns error messages and fails to post when I submit, even when fields aren't empty. Any help or other suggestions on this?

```html
<template>
<b-row align-v="center">
      <b-col cols="8">
        <b-form-group method="post" @submit="postData">
          <b-form-group
            id="input-group-1"
            label-for="input-1"
            description="Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person."
          >
            <b-form-input
              type="text"
              name="questionTitle"
              v-model="posts.questionTitle"
              placeholder="Title"
              required
            />
          </b-form-group>
          <b-button-toolbar>
            <b-button-group class="mr-1">
              <b-button
                class="input-file__button"
                title="Load file"
                ref="file"
                type="file"
                required
              >
                <b-icon
                  class="input-file__input"
                  icon="upload"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  @click="selectFile()"
                  required
                ></b-icon>
              </b-button>
            </b-button-group>
          </b-button-toolbar>
          <b-form-input
            id="question-input"
            type="text"
            name="description"
            v-model="posts.description"
            placeholder="description"
            required
          />
          <br />
          <div class="hero-info">choose category :</div>
          <b-row class="categories-row">
            <div
              class="categories"
              v-for="(category, index) in categories"
              :key="index"
              @click="Add(category._id, index)"
              :class="[selectedIndex.includes(index) ? 'green' : 'gray']"
              required
            >
              {{ category.category_name }}
            </div>
          </b-row>
          <button @click="RemoveAll">remove selected category</button>

          <br />
          <div class="input-file">
            <input
              class="input-file__input"
              id="upload"
              @change="log_file_name()"
              ref="file"
              type="file"
              name="file"
              required
            />
            <!-- <div class="input-file__button" @click="selectFile()"></div> -->
          </div>
          <br />
          <b-button class="primary" type="submit" @click="postData"
            >Post</b-button
          >
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <p v-if="error.length" >
     <li v-for="(e,index) in error" :key="index" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
     {{e}}
     </li>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "postComponent",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      file_path: null,
      selectedIndex: [],
      isediting: false,
      AddCategory: [],
      error: [],

      posts: {
        description: null,
        questionTitle: null,
        categories: null,
        file_path: null,
        owner: null,
        solver: null,
        reviewed: false,
      },
    };
  },

methods: postData() {
        if(!this.questionTitle){
    this.error.push('enter title');
  }
   if(!this.description){
    this.error.push('enter description');
  }
   if(!this.categories){
    this.error.push('enter categories');
  }
   if(!this.file_path){
    this.error.push('enter file');
  }
      
         if(this.questionTitle && this.description){
         console.log('login called');
  
        this.posts.categories = this.AddCategory;
        this.posts.file_path = this.file_path;
        this.posts.owner = "5fda8e3df24cbf0004080b8d";
        this.posts.solver = "5fda8e3df24cbf0004080b8d";
        this.posts.reviewed = false;

         axios
          .post(
            "/api/add",
            this.posts
          )

          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);

            // this.posts.reviewed=this.reviewed

            // this.$router.push("/questions");
                  // e.preventDefault();
          });

          this.error= []
  }
 
    },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `postData` method you are checking for the input data, like so:

```js
if(!this.questionTitle) { }
```

But your form items `v-model` properties are hooked to the `posts` object in your component data, so your code should look like this:

```js
if(!this.posts.questionTitle) { }
```

You need to change this for all the posts properties you check out send during submission.

Comment: appreciated ! that worked i didn't pay attention to it